# xPath of JSON response in soapUI

Tags: json, xpath, soapui

can anyone help in finding xpath of 'tenantId' which is in JSON response given below

```
{
   "statusCode": "200",
   "errorParams": null,
   "payLoad":    {
      "UGX:XCD":       {
         "id": 42802,
         "fromCurrency":          {
            "tenantId": "2a610af6-2e42-4a78-8e04-98755e2c6113",
            "code": "UGX",
            "name": "Ugandan Shilling",
            "isoCode": "UGX",
            "active": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "flagModifiedName": false,
            "erpId": null,
            "createdOn": 1427155200000,
            "fieldLibraryStatus": "DRAFT",
            "userId": null
         },
         "toCurrency":          {
            "tenantId": "2a610af6-2e42-4a78-8e04-98755e2c6113",
            "code": "XCD",
            "name": "East Caribbean Dollar",
            "isoCode": "XCD",
            "active": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "flagModifiedName": true,
            "erpId": null,
            "createdOn": 1427155200000,
            "fieldLibraryStatus": "DRAFT",
            "userId": "c7f68b05-044d-44e1-8fc5-0f97a4ece91b"
         },
         "rate": 33,
         "inverseRate": 0.0303,
         "createdOn": 1434025926983,
         "modifiedOn": 1434326400000,
         "active": true,
         "purpose": "cmd",
         "enabled": true,
         "tenantFlag": true,
         "erpId": null
      }
```

How to traverse till 'tenantId' ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: XPath is used for selecting parts of an XML document. It has rudimentary string-processing abilities but would not be a good tool for traversing a JSON data structure. If you tell us what environment you were wanting to use XPath in, maybe we can suggest a better way to process the JSON data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoapUI internally converts *almost* anything to XML. You will have to use the `ResponseAsXml` property. In the GUI, if you click on the XML tab, you can see this representation.

Something like the following should work:

```
${test_step#ResponseAsXml#//*:fromCurrency/*:tenantId}
${test_step#ResponseAsXml#//*:toCurrency/*:tenantId}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this using groovy, then extend SOAPUI with GSON.jar library provided by Google.
this library specially written to handle the JSON objects.

With this you can rip every individual objects and its attribute-values easily how complex may the JSON object be, a nice add-on to work with.

Comment: I think that this is not necessary, groovy in the gdk has http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html which is a good class to work with Json `:)`.